# Permanently setting intel pstate driver to "passive"

Tags: intel, cpu, cpufreq, proc

My i5-11600K CPU is using the [intel_pstate](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html) frequency scaling.

By default, the driver is in "active" mode and will throttle up ALL 6 physical cores, even if there is only work for one core.

To fix this, I do:

```
# echo "passive" >  /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status
```

But after a reboot, that setting is gone again.

How can I permanently set intel_pstate mode to `passive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver to startup as the intel_cpufreq driver (A.K.A. intel_pstate in passive mode) via the kernel command line. You can select the desired CPU frequency scaling governor the same way.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to include what is desired by adding directives to what is already there.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_pstate=passive cpufreq.default_governor=schedutil"
```

Remember to do `sudo update-grub` afterwards, and save the copy of grub before editing.

Now, Ubuntu also has a service that might override the desired governor, setting it to ondemand. It can be disabled:

```
sudo systemctl disable ondemand
```

I also prefer to disable HWP (HardWare Pstate) control so my actual grub command line is:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=450 intel_pstate=passive intel_pstate=no_hwp cpufreq.default_governor=schedutil msr.allow_writes=on cpuidle.governor=teo"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me to remove Intel_pstate driver from existance and use ACPI:driver

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=UB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_pstate=disable acpi=force"`

and update grub

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

and check

`cpufreq-info`